# PHP pass and receive two dimensional array from form

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass two paired variables, a category and its id for multiple user-created categories from a webform to a file for processing.  I want to keep them linked so if someone changes the name field, we are clear what record they are changing as this record is linked to other tables by id.

Originally tried two dimensional array...have abandoned that approach.  Now trying to use two one dimensional arrays as per suggestion below.  I am going with arrays because number of entries on form depends on how many categories user has created.  Categories table has id(int), cat(text) and userid(int) fields

Difficulty with passing two arrays is how to link the two. If I pass categories as array to receiving page, I can iterate through values to produce sql statements to change each entry.  However, I can't figure out how to get correct id which is needed to identify record.  If I use a foreach($idarray as $id) inside the foreach(catsarray as $val) I will get multiple ids for each cat.  How do I iterate through ids in synch with iterating through cats?  Many thanks for help as I have now spent two days on this :(

```
//I am working with $catsarray and $idarray, each with identical indexes, 1,2,3 etc.
//How do I get appropriate id for each cat
foreach($catsarray as $val) {
$sql = "UPDATE cats, set name = $val WHERE (userid ='$userid' AND id=??????)";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

good and single syntax for creating two dimensional array;

```
  <input type="text" name="cat[]" value="cat1">
  <input type="text" name="cat[]" value="cat2">
    ...
```

While receiving cats;

```
echo $_POST['cat'][0] // echoes cat1
echo $_POST['cat'][1] // echoes cat2
```

Further example;

According to this definition,

```
<input type="text" name="cat[$cat][$id]" value="cat1">

foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $a=>$b){
    // $a == $cat
    foreach($b as $c=>$d) {
       // $c == $id
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with @miqbal, rather than trying to have a two dimensional array with both cat and id in it, just create two one-dim arrays, one for cat and the other for id. Then loop both together in the POST side.

Comment: Using a variation of 2nd example, <input type = "text" name = "cat[$i][name]" value="cat1"> and <input type = "hidden" name = "cat[$i][id]" value =id1, I have passed what looks to be a valid array (echoes as Array).  Should I use a foreach and loop through to get values of each?  Does the $a==>$b take the place of $val in a one dimensional array so I can then invoke $a or $b as needed?  Many thx!

Comment: `$a=>$b` means key=>value. Our keys are $cat and $id that we want to send to server. Notice `$b` is a id Array that belongs to $a category. To be more understandable, design your form to 2nd example and see `print_r($_POST['cat']);`

Comment: I printed out.  So I can use $a above and $c as cat and id respectively?

Comment: Using your exact syntax $a echoes $cat and $c echoes Array.  Suggestions?

Comment: my mistake...have gotten to: UPDATE cats, set name = '\' cat\'' WHERE (userid ='1' AND id='\'2\'').

Comment: And using strip slashes and removing ticks from $a and $c have good sql statement.  Only problem is the array is not picking up a changed value on the form.  ie it is still showing "dogs" from value="dogs" even when you type cats into the textbox...

Comment: have abandoned 2 dim approach.  Now trying 2 1-dimensions but need to link two.  See edited question above.

Comment: Final comment for googlers.  Best Solution as suggested is append [] to end of names for entries.  These will automatically post to a valid array.  To link the two: when you do foreach loop on first variable, set up a counter and within foreach reference 2nd variable as var2[$i] where i is counter.  Phew.  Easy, once you know how.