# php what is a valid array form? slashes and tick marks

Tags: php, arrays

this is driving me crazy so any help is much appreciated.

I am posting records with name=opc[1] cat[2] etc.  Ideally this would created an array.  When I print_r the posted data, it prints what looks like an array though with ticks and slashes around the keys.

However, when I set a variable, $array or whatever equal to the array, print_r($array) returns 0.  Echo returns Array.

Possibly related to this, when I try to do foreach on the array, it gives an invalid argument error.  What do I need to do to the posted data so that I can set it to a variable and use it as a valid array.  I've tried various combinations of implode, explode and stripslashes to put it into better form but only the $_POST prints out in print_r.  Implode generates an error.  Explode creates an Array with just 1 item.

Here is print_r($_POST['opc']);

```
Array ( [\'0\'] => dog [\'1\'] => cat [\'2\'] => mouse [\'3\'] => chicken [\'4\'] => runner [\'5\'] => )
```

What do I need to do to work with this?

form code (first two records):

```
<tr><form action="editcats.php" method="post"><td align="right">Existing:</td><td align="left"><input type="text" size="12" name="ocp[0]" value="dog"><input type="hidden" name="id[0]" value="1"></tr>
<tr><td align="right"></td><td align="left"><input type="text" size="12" name="ocp[1]" value="cat"><input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form></tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for the form?

Comment: There are two types of arrays in php. An array, and an associative with key => value.  $myArray[] = 1;  will put 1 in $myArray[0].  In an associative array you have a key.  $myArray['dog'] = 'Spot'; $myArray['cat'] = 'Boots';

Comment: Are you posting an array as a text string? also it seems you may have magic_quotes enabled.

Comment: It looks like your entire 'array' is actually one element with magic_quotes enabled, as a string. What and how are you passing the item to the Array?

Comment: just added code.  Array should be concatenating, I think, from name=opc[0] in first, name=opc[1] in 2nd etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your HTML source code, it appears that you are mixing up the method on how to pass an array variable to `$_POST`. You shouldn't have two elements with the same 'name' either, even if you wish them to post to the same array. Either rectify your method for entering data into the array variable, or name the elements differently.

Remove the indices from your `name` attribute and try running your form again.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180810/php-pass-and-receive-two-dimensional-array-from-form) for some help as well.

```
<input type="text" size="12" name="ocp[]" value="cat"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form></tr>
```

Comment: `name='opc[]'` Take a look at [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) on the PHP.net site about arrays/HTML forms.

Comment: Ok.  that did the trick.  Related question... I want to use the id in the hidden input on the other side...Iterating through the names, is there a way to relate these to the ids?  This is question you linked to but no answer yet.  Thx!

Comment: The PHP.net link shows how you can give the array a named element. I would suggest creating a second assoc array with the id numbers you want as values and the IDS from the `opc` as the key. Then, you could look up the value in your second array and assign or use with the `opc[]` in PHP as needed.