# Post Multiple Values from a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

I am programming a fantasy pet game. Currently, I am working on a tool to help users manage their personal shop inventory. The tool includes options to change the sale price of each item - and that's where my problem is. Here, let me show you:

**The HTML**

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="cost[$item_id]" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

$item_id is a variable that corresponds to the item which is being edited. It must be included in the array, otherwise... I won't know which price corresponds to what item.

Also, this script:

```
<input type="text" name="cost[$item_id]" value="" />
```

is repeated for the amount of items in the shop's inventory. So, the form can include an unlimited amount of these entries. Hence the array.

**The Script**

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

foreach ($_POST['cost'] as $key => $value) {
$submitted_array = array_keys($_POST['cost']); 
echo ($_POST['cost'][$submitted_array[0]] . " " . $submitted_array[0]); 
}

}
```

The script above works... however, it will only print the first set of data from the array.

Now, that seems fine - BUT, remember how I said I could have an unlimited amount of cost entries? That's my problem - when I use a variable to replace the "0" in the script above, the function stops working all together. I could repeat the function, if I knew how many entries total the array would include - but I don't. So what can I do? Is there a simple solution to my problem?

Adding a hidden field to the form that specifies how many items are being changed is possible - I just don't know if it would be helpful.

If you would like to see a screen caption of the form to get a better understanding of what I'm talking about, just ask and you will receive!

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180810/php-pass-and-receive-two-dimensional-array-from-form/10180886

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're rewriting the `$submitted_array` variable multiple times, when you only need once.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $submitted_array = array_keys($_POST['cost']);
    foreach ($_POST['cost'] as $key => $value) {
        echo ($_POST['cost'][$submitted_array[0]] . " " . $submitted_array[0]);
    }
}
```

Also, considering your `cost` array, you don't need to use `array_keys` at all:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['cost'] as $item_ID => $item_cost) {
        echo ($item_ID . " " . $item_cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that answer, but it still only posts the first set of data. It does print X amount of times, but.. it only posts 1 set of data.

Comment: It works PERFECTLY! =D Thank you SO much for the great, and quick, help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Connie, please vote up and, most important, mark the answer as correct. It's a pleasure help others here. :)